# Sort a php array getting the times a number appears in other array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, counting

I'm trying to achieve a list of ordered score points a user received and the number of times he received each score using the array that comes from the database `$user_rating_points`. The base score values are defined as an array of possible points `$score_points`.

Imagining that the query for a user gives me the following array for his given points:

```
    // The base score points' scale
    $score_points = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    // The array of points a user received (from the database query)
    $user_rating_points = [1, 3, 2, 7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 10, 6, 1, 7, 10, 8, 4, 8, 9, 4, 7, 10, 5];
```

I want to achieve something like the following:

- 1 point: 3 times
- 2 points: 2 times
- 3 points: 5 times
- ...
- 9 points: 2 times
- 10 points: 3 times

I've tried using the `array_count_values($user_rating_points)` with `sort($user_rating_points);` but either on a HTML ul or a `print_r($user_rating_points)` I'm unable to get a list like the above example.

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue that is probably much simpler to solve than I expect, yet it seems like I've gone into a loop and not finding a solution.

Comment: The `"what you want to achieve"` suggests there are 3 of #1 in `$user_rating_points`  yet I can see only 2. The same for #3 where I can see only 2. Is that just dummy data or some other criteria I've missed?

Comment: It means score 1 was given 3 times, score 2 was given 2 times, and son and so forth. Yes, it's dummy data not to pile the post with a bunch of real data. From here I presume I will be able to figure it out.

Comment: So you are saying that there ought to be 3 of #1 in `$user_rating_points` as it was awarded 3 times? The same for the other numbers? ie `10 points` awarded 3 times so will appear 3 times in `$user_rating_points`?

Comment: Yes, correct. I wish to get the list of how many times the user got scored for each of the 1 to 10 score points. Scored 1 point 2 times; scored 2 points 33 times, scored 10 points 5 times, etc.

Comment: well that is what `array_count_values` will give you so I'm confused why you think otherwise. Looking at the arrays given there is a discrepancy with what you want and what the arrays contain. Are the `what you want` examples accurately based upon the arrays given here or just `for example`??

Comment: Yes, they are, but with the `array_count_values` I get the keys 0,1,2,3... instead of 1,2,3...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241515/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-mcrui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_combine(
    $score_points,
    array_map(
        fn($score_point) => count(
            array_filter($user_rating_points, fn($value) => $value === $score_point)
        ),
        $score_points
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks @lukas.j it works and it becomes much simpler code using the `array_map()` with callback

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.
Keys are sorted 1->10, no 0.
If you have points which appear 0 times, they will also be present in the results.

```
<?php
// The base score points' scale
$score_points = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// The array of points a user received (from the database query)
$user_rating_points = [1, 3, 2, 7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 10, 6, 1, 7, 10, 8, 4, 8, 9, 4, 7, 10, 5];
$user_score = array_fill_keys($score_points, 0);
foreach (array_count_values($user_rating_points) as $k => $v) {
    $user_score[$k] = $v;
}
print_r($user_score);
```

?>

And the output is

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 3
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Marcel Preda, that's what I was looking for. Now I know what I was missing... the `array_fill()` call. :(

Comment: The line _$user_score = array_fill(1, 10, 0);_ could (and maybe should) be  be based on the values from $score_points. If ever the $user_score array is changed (for example to 1..12), the code won't work anymore.

Comment: The code will also not work, if the $score_points have gaps, like in some sports: [ 25, 15, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ].

Comment: Good point.  I've edited the answer to use $score_points  values as keys.